# MacOS 14 bug? The Folder-Albums relations that I created in Photos didn't persist. They reverted after a few days

Tags: macos, photos, sonoma

A few days ago I upgrade to Mac OS 14.0, I found the Photos app supports Folders therefore I created some Folders and moved Albums into Folders, and those changes were synced to iPhone as well.

Howevere today I found all the work that I did were gone. The Albums are still listed under the root "My Albums", and the folders that I created are empty. Some albums which I've changed the name have reverted to the orignal name.

It seems to me that my changes Photos were simply lost.

Comment: Is there another device that syncs with your iCloud account?